# How to declare a 16-element character array?

Tags: c++, arrays

The question goes....

"Declare a 16 element character array with global scope. Fill it with letters A to P in fillArray(), output the array forward in forwardArray(), and then output the array backwards in backArray()."

EDIT: I was basing the new problem off this. But as ive said. I was pulling my hair out trying. I was just going to ask help tomorrow but forgot there were sites like this one that can further explain it to you.

```
main()
fillArray()
fowardArray()
backArray()
```

////////////////////////////

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << setprecision(3)
 << setiosflags(ios::fixed)
 << setiosflags(ios::showpoint);

int I, length;
char name[80];

cout << "Enter your first name good sir/miss! ";
cin >> name;

cout << "\nHello " << name << "\n\n";
length=0;
I=0;
while(name[I] !='\0')
{
    length++;

    I++;
}


cout << "Using our inline strlen function:\n " << name << ", the number of characters in your name is ";
cout << length;

cout << "\n\nUsing the library strlen() function:\n " << name << ", the number of characters    in your name is ";
cout << strlen(name);

//PartB---------------------------------------------------------------------------

int alphalength=0;

I=0;

while(name[I]!='\0')
{   

name[I]>='A'&& name[I]<='Z'||name[I]>='a'&& name[I]<='z';

if(isalpha(name[I])!=0)
    alphalength++;

    I++;
}


cout << "\n\n\n\n" << name << " the number of alphabetic characters in your name is ";
cout << alphalength << "\n\n";






system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't write some function signatures there and expect people to fill those for you, show what you have tried.

Comment: @Harkins1721 have you managed to create some array in some file? please show the code

Comment: One day little Alice went to the market and met the wizard of Oz!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about completing an assignment for the poster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that you tried this on your own first. In any case, I am happy to help.

Note the nuance on the array bounds for going forward and backward. The forward case indices go from 0 to 15. The reverse case goes from 15 to 0.

In fillArray(), the code leverages the fact that chars are internally stored as integers, and the letters are represented in order, so 'A'+1 is 'B', etc.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int NUM_ELEMENTS = 16;

//Declare a 16 element character array with global scope.
char yourArray[NUM_ELEMENTS];

//Fill it with letters A to P in fillArray(), 
void fillArray()
{
    char iterChar = 'A';

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; i++)
    {
        yourArray[i] = iterChar;
        iterChar++;
    }
}

//output the array forward in forwardArray(),
void forwardArray()
{
    cout << "Forward Array [";

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; i++)
    {
        cout << yourArray[i];
    }

    cout <<"]" << endl;
}    

//and then output the array backwards in backArray()."
void backwardArray()
{
    cout << "Backward Array [";

    for (int i = NUM_ELEMENTS-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << yourArray[i];
    }

    cout << "]" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    fillArray();
    forwardArray();
    backwardArray();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to start somewhere.

Comment: Ive edited my post to show you what ive done recently. I cant show you the actual code I tried because its gone. I gave up on it and was waiting until tomorrow to seek help. Im sure you dont believe me but it was only 15 lines of code and was nothing close to what you have posted. But I just wanted to say thank you for the help. I cant learn anything off my teacher. And the code above is something that took me forever to find out how to do correctly.

Comment: I recommend you at least type it out yourself, instead of copy-pasting it. You may make a small error you need to work through, and it will be good practice. And you will have at least comprehended and regenerated the code. Oh, and if you can click the "accept" button for my answer, that would be appreciated.

Comment: @Dutch thats what im here for! Typing it does help me out. Quite a lot actually. But when you dont do this kind of coding more than once its a pain. Thank you for not being vague and with the added comments in the code. It helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware declaring things in a global scope is considered bad practice, and therefore should be avoided, but if you have to:

```
#include <iostream>

char array[16];

int main()
{
#Your code

return 0;
}
```

If you use that, the character array "array" is in the global scope.
If you want to fill it with A to P, just start off your code in main() with a while loop that initializes the array, and then create the other functions you need.

Comment: I think you are really not helping her/him this way...

Comment: If he wants more help, he can just make a comment. Sometimes people just take a bit of time to understand programming logic.

Comment: didn't mean to be rude, I totally agree, but in my humble opinion this not the place for her/him to learn, answers are not meant to solve homework problems.

Comment: @Dimitrios hahaha this "homework" doesnt even get counted. Its just a few problem my teacher has kinda hinted being similar on a test in a few weeks. And being as vague as he is I have to seek help here sometimes and usually with my friend. Im actually trying to understand the problem. Thats why its been 3 months since my last question. Before today of course.

Comment: Hey, Dutch Oven made a really good solution to your problem, below.

Comment: @GriffinG. Yup yup! Im just trying to figure a way of showing a code I tried a few weeks ago similar to this one. Im very slow at this lol. But i do appreciate all the replies and help. One week im in and done while another I pull out my hair wondering what the hell im doing wrong.